# How to find the PDB files when attaching to an already running program in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

I've been debugging a browser plugin lately. The debugging process goes like this:

1) Build new plugin and register it with regsvr32.
2) Run browser.
3) Attach to browser process with visual studio.

Whenever I attach to the browser process I never get any symbols in my call stacks... Breakpoints work however... But I really need to be able to see what the threads are doing...

The .pdb files are located right next to the libraries the browser plugin depends upon. How can I tell Visual Studio about the location of the PDB files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Options -> Debugging -> Symbols and add the directory into there.

Answer (score 0):

The location of the .pdb is usually contained in the module.  Are you moving the pdb from where it was originally created?  Also, seems odd that breakpoints work without symbols being present.  Does the debug output window explicitly note that the symbols were not found?